# How to clean unfinished repo sync

Tags: android, android-source, repo

I am trying to download android source using repo tool. Due to low bandwidth it hasn't finished downloading after several days. Now I want to clean up all the recieve files. How to do that? I don't see any clean command for the  repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can continue downloading the repository just run:

```
repo sync
```

If you want to clean the repository just delete whats under .repo, its a hidden directory